# gitignore pattern with leading double asterisk (without whitelisting)

Tags: gitignore

I have the following entry in my .gitignore file (and note that there are no whitelisted entries in my .gitignore):

```
**.X/.generated_files/
```

... but this filename (and hundreds of other) are not ignored as I would expect:

```
MPLAB/demo_a/firmware/my_project.X/.generated_files/flags/my_project/298af8995f15611bb06320c3cd979f12c9e52659
```

What am I missing?

(Update: I've also tried `**.X/.generated_files` and `**.X/.generated_files/*`, but no joy...)

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, I found an MPLAB project on github with the following:

```
**/*.X/.generated_files
```

Works like a champ.  Thanks, Google!  Thanks, Internet!  Thanks, github!